# SOLVED: Error al editar un registro con CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Al momento de editar una entrada me genera el siguiente error:

> Deprecated (16384): Using key `action` is deprecated, use `url` directly instead. [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper.php, line 383]

al editar y darle save post o update me aparece esto:

> Deprecated (16384): Validation::notEmpty() is deprecated. Use Validation::notBlank() instead. [CORE\Cake\Utility\Validation.php, line 60]
>
> Deprecated (16384): Validation::notEmpty() is deprecated. Use Validation::notBlank() instead. [CORE\Cake\Utility\Validation.php, line 60]

Ya hice las correcciones que me indicaron, pero al ejecutar el CRUD, en el edit, no guarda la edicion del post, me genera el siguiente error:

> Error: The requested address '/cakephp2/posts/edit' was not found on this server.

SOLUCION:

> cambie 'action' por 'id' y no por 'url'

Comment: ¿Qué versión de CakePHP utilizas? Y también, podrías poner el código que da origen al error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esas funciones fueron marcadas para removerse en la versión 2 de cake

El primer error indica que en vez de usar `'action'` en la configuración del formulario lo cambies por `'url'`

```
echo $this->Form->create(false, array(
    'url' => array('controller' => 'recipes', 'action' => 'add'),
    'id' => 'RecipesAdd'
));
```

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#

El segundo error indica que a tus llamados de validación 
`notEmpty` los cambies por `notBlank`

```
public $validate = array(
    'title' => array(
        'rule' => 'notBlank',
        'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank'
    )
);
```

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::notEmpty

Comment: Al cambiar los parametros indicados me da el siguiente error: Error: `The requested address '/cakephp2/posts/edit' was not found on this server.`

Comment: que métodos tienes en tu controlador posts

Comment: me da el error es con el edit, no puedo pegar el codigo por exceso de caracteres...

Comment: En el edit o en el controlador?

Comment: me da el error cuando estoy probando editar un post, puedo eliminar y agregar uno nuevo pero no guarda las ediciones

Comment: porque no funcionarian las validaciones del formulario en el update, pero en el agregado si.